# (Django) How to add a queryset count for dynamic objects in a list to a template?

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I am building a website with django as a place to store my university notes.

I have a notes model which is linked by foreignkey to a categories model.

On my homepage I use a for loop to post a link to each category page, but in brackets I also wanted to display the number of published notes in that category.

For example:

Biology (6)
Chemistry (4)
Physics (12)

etc etc

I use template tag to give the length eg. {{category.notes_set.all|length}} within the for loop to display the number of notes in a category, but this ignores whether the notes are published or whether they are just created. It would give a value of 7 if I had 6 published and 1 unpublished note - I want it to display 6. I really want to filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()) but don't think this can be achieved in template.

Do I have to create a context dictionary for every single category and annotate it with the count within the view? I feel this would be unmanageable when the number of categories and sub-categories becomes very large. Can I do this as a for loop within views.py?

Sorry if this has an obvious answer, I am a true beginner.

Most recent EDIT: It seems that the most elegant solution is to add a function to my model class in models.py, as per Ben's answer. So for the case-studies landing page I add:

```
def published_cases(self):
    return self.case_set.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

to my Specialty model. Then I add {{specialty.published_cases.all|length}} to my template.

Thanks for the help everyone.

EDIT: I am attempting to incorporate the annotate function into my class based views. Here is some example code for my case-studies landing page. It displays a list of new case-studies, top rated case-studies and a list of specialties which I want to annotate with a count of published case-studies. I have tried the following code:

```
class CaseListView(TemplateView):
template_name = "case_list.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CaseListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["cases"] = Case.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by("-published_date")[:5]
    context["topcases"] = Case.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).annotate(num_upvotes=Count("upvotes")).order_by("-num_upvotes")[:5]
    context["specialtys"] = Specialty.objects.all().order_by("name").annotate(num_cases=Count("case", filter=Q(case__published_date__lte=timezone.now())))
    return context
```

This is giving me a NameError (Exception Value: name 'Q' is not defined).

I tried another method of building the context:

```
context["specialtys"] = Specialty.objects.all().order_by("name").annotate(num_cases=Count("case")).filter(case__published_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

This did not raise an exception, but did not give the desired result, giving a wildly incorrect value for {{specialty.num_cases}} which with my level of knowledge I can't even begin to imagine how it calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a method to the Category model that only returns published notes:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ... model definition ...

    def published_notes(self):
        return self.notes_set.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

And use that in the template instead:

```
{{ category.published_notes|length }}
```

The method could well be useful elsewhere in the project too. You're likely to want to do the same logic of only-published-notes in multiple places.

Comment: I'll give this a go.

Comment: Just tested this method and it seems the most elegant solution, thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/). In your view you can annotate each category with the count of its related notes, filtering the count to published notes only.

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
categories = Category.objects.annotate(note_count=Count("note", filter=Q(note__published_date__lte=timezone.now())))
```

Now each category has an attribute `note_count` which has the number of published notes.

Comment: This wouldn’t give you anything different to the way the OP is currently doing it, surely? It wouldn’t filter out unpublished notes.

Comment: Updated with a filter so it counts published notes only.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I think that this is what I have been looking for.

I'm having trouble incorporating it into my class based views though, I have edited my original question to show how I have tried.